# cut vs findInterval

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to reproduce a table by simulation, the table consists of two columns: Day and number of successes.

```
---------------------
|   Day | successes |
---------------------
|   2   |   12500   |
|   3   |   15900   |
|   4   |   18450   |
|   5   |   21000   |
|   6   |   23450   |
|   7   |   24000   |
|   8   |   25000   |
|   9   |   26050   |
|   10  |   26550   |
|   11  |   27500   |
|   12  |   27600   |
|   13  |   27600   |
|   14  |   28150   |
|   15  |   28500   |
---------------------
```

the population consists of two groups, `n.group1= 38700 and n.group2=11300`
I'm asuming time until a succes is exponentially distributed with theta1 for group1 and theta2 for group2. and for some theoritical reasons `theta1>theta2`
I'm generating time using `rexp` in r, then I'm classifying time into day categories
For this porpuse, I'm using two different functions:

```
#cut function
c.fun <- function(m){
  c <- cut(m, breaks = c(-Inf, 2:15, Inf), right = FALSE)
  c <-as.data.frame(table(c))
  c<- as.data.frame(c[-15,-1])
  row.names(c) <- c(2:15)
  colnames(c)="Freq"
  return(c)
}
```

and the second is

```
# using findInterval
find.int <- function(d){
  d<-as.data.frame(table(findInterval(d, c(1:cat.end))))
  d[2,2] <- sum(d[1:2,2]) # adding category 1 and 2 together
  d <- d[-c(1, 16:cat.end),]
  d$Var1<-NULL
  return(d)
}
```

then summing them up to looks like the observed data

```
get.total <- function(theta){
  #group1
  group1 <-rexp(n.group1, rate=theta[1])

  #group2
  group2 <-rexp(n.group2, rate=theta[2])

  #Classifying
  #group1
  group1<-find.int(group1)
  #or group1<-c.fun(group1)

  #group2
  group2<-find.int(group2)
  #or group2<-c.fun(group2)

  total <- data.frame(group1, group2)
  colnames(total)<- c("group1", "group2")
  total$group1 <- cumsum(total$group1)
  total$group2 <- cumsum(total$group2)
  total$total <- total$group1+total$group2
  #total$total <- cumsum(total$total)
  return(total$total)
}
```

and then calculate the mean square error and use a 3d plot to make a decision on which theta I should choose.

```
mse.fn <- function(theta){
  mse(get.total(theta),observed.data$successes)
}
```

I'm getting different results from those two functions, and I'm wondering which one is correct?
Also, I'm using `optim` built-in function to find the best theta combination, but it gives me a negative value for theta2 which is not realistic?

```
optim(theta<-c(0.1,0.1), mse.fn)$par
```

and the same with `optimx`

```
optimx(theta<-c(0.1,0.1, mse.fn)
```

I'll be grateful if someone can see where I made the mistake.

Comment: This is a lot of material. Here is one point of comparison: `identical(as.integer(cut(1:10, c(-Inf,2, 5, 8,Inf), right = FALSE))-1L,  findInterval(1:10, c(2, 5, 8)))` returns TRUE. The `-1L` and `as.integer` are not necessary in terms of partitioning the set.

Comment: @Imo, Thanks but I'm asking which one is accurate? I don't want to compare them because there are differences in the results.